# How to search for lines with 2 (or more) specific words in sublime?

Tags: replace, find, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I would like to search for lines which contains 2 (or more) specific words. For example I have multiple occurrences of `my function` in project:

`my_function('test', 'test2')`

`my_function('test3', 'test4')`

`my_function(nil, 'test5')`

etc.

I would like to look only for those occurrences which contains `nil`.

Any way of doing that using Sublime's `Find in files`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This RegEx pattern gives you a high degree of control over what characters are allowed within the function:

`my_function\([a-zA-Z0-9,-_'"\s]*?nil[a-zA-Z0-9,-_'"\s]*?\)`

Alternatively, if you want a simpler match that finds any line which contains `my_function` followed by `nil`, use:

`my_function.*nil`

Or to match any line which contains both `my_function` & `nil`, in any order, use:

`(my_function.*nil)|(nil.*my_function)`

[image: RegEx Demo]

---

---

#### Breakdown:

**[1]**     `my_function\(`
    **[2]**     `[a-zA-Z0-9,-_'"\s]*?`
    **[3]**     `nil`
    **[4]**     `[a-zA-Z0-9,-_'"\s]*?`
    **[5]**     `\)`

**Groups 1 & 5 contain escaped parentheses.**

**Groups 2 & 4 contain a character set that matches:**
all alphanumeric characters, commas, underscores, single quotes, double quotes, & whitespace

---

---

More info @:

## [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qW0pV3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Open `Find in files` and enable Regular expressions (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut).

Then use this regex to find the occurences `my_function\((.*)?nil(.*)?\)`

Answer (score -1):

first press ctrl+shift+f then type in find and where with below query

```
Find: (string1|string2)
Where: <path of the folder>
```